# is it possible to use git for version control in enterprise architect

Tags: git, enterprise-architect

Hi have started to use (SparX) Enterprise Architect 13 for more complex models.
In my company we use git for version control and I would like us to be able to use it for version control for our models as I do not want to start using tortoise svn or tfs.

How do I integrate enterprise architect 13 with git?

Comment: Look at LemonTree from LieberLieber. EA can only integrate with "classical" VC systems.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, at least not using out-of-the-box EA version control.

The reason is that EA requires exclusive locks on the checked-out files, and such a thing is by design not possible in distributed version control systems such as GIT.

The commercial add-in [LemonTree](https://www.lieberlieber.com/lemontree/en/) could be a solution if you are desperate for a solution using GIT.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer. that was the only package I could find for it also. I was hoping that there will be larger selection for this.